# How many essential ways: $n$ balls in $k$ bins, where $k$ can vary and there are $\geq 2$ balls in each bin?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For instance. $n = 1 \implies 1$, same is true for $n = 2, 3, 4$.  Then at $n = 5$ we have result  $= 2$, since: $\{5\}, \{3, 2\}$.  Also I am identifying $\{3,2\} = \{2, 3\}$.  I think there is probably a nicer way to state this problem.

Comment: Seems like partitions, where each pile has one or more ball, but with added restriction that each pile has 2 or more balls. That might not be already studied, but some of the subformulas used in usual partitions might be useful, like $P(n,k)$ the number of partitions into $k$ piles (each 1 or more). That could be used to express your number (not in closed form).

Comment: @coffeemath are there any obvious bounds as $n$ grows?

Comment: Enjoys-- a trivial one: its bounded above by the total number of partitions of $n.$ [that's likely much larger than need be.]