# How does partition function $p(n)/n!$ grow (big-O, etc)?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, computational-complexity, integer-partitions

Specifically, I am interested only in partitions with at least the amount of $2$ in each bucket, but intuitively it doesn't matter?

I have no idea how to work with those complex asymptotic growth formulas.  Looking for a simple approximation such as: looks exponential, or looks logarithmic.

Comment: How precise do you need this?  It decays faster than $e^{ -n}$.

Comment: @quid, the sequence I need an approximation or bound of is: $1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, \dots$ are you saying that it eventually decays?

Comment: @quid, it's to count these babies: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957311/how-many-essential-ways-n-balls-in-k-bins-where-k-can-vary-and-there-are

Comment: I have no idea what your sequence should be. Anyway $3$ has $3$ partitions, namely $1+1+1$, $1+2$, $3$ while $3!=6$. So the third term of the sequence in OP is $1/2$.

Comment: @ quid, no 1: {3}, because there must be at least 2 in each bucket.

Comment: Yes, I ignored that on purpose. But it makes it worse. So the third term is $1/6$ then.

Comment: @quid, I think I just mean $p(n)$ then, since it already takes into account different "orderings" or permutations.

Comment: The partitions function grows roughly like $\exp( \sqrt{2n/3})$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function I am  not sure about the exact influence of your extra condition. I think it could have a relvant effect.

Comment: @quid ask him to define his partition function, it is not ours at all

Comment: they could be the partition where the order counts (and no $1$ appears), so the partition of $5$ are $5,2+3, 3+2$ in that case the generating function is $f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g(z)^k = \frac{g(z)}{1-g(z)}$ where $g(z) = z^2+z^3+z^4+\ldots = \frac{z^2}{1-z}$

Comment: @user1952009 given the starting snippet that's not the case. Other than that I recommend you ask OP yourself rather than to bother me.

Comment: @quid I'm not bothering you, just saying that he didn't get what you wrote since the beginning because he didn't think to the same function

Comment: @user1952009 check the linked to question and you'll see it is about the usual partition function where each part is at least $2$. Anyway the page I linked to includes a defintion of the function I am talking about. So if OP wants something else they'll see and can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each part at least 2, is equivalent to "without any part =1", and is given in http://oeis.org/A002865. 
GF:  Product_{m>1} 1/(1-x^m)
recursion :a(n)= p(n)-p(n-1)
and a(n) ~ Pi * exp(sqrt(2*n/3)*Pi) / (12*sqrt(2)*n^(3/2))